# Why does this work? PHP Direct array value from function

Tags: php, arrays

I was questioning myself, why does this work?

```
$key = 'question_1';
$key = explode('_', $key)[1];
var_dump($key); 

Result: string(1) "1"
```

A collegue of mine used this, but how is this called?

Comment: We don't know why *you* haven't seen this before, but it's widely used across many languages and is called *array dereferencing*. PHP has gotten it pretty late actually.

Comment: It's called [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). You didn't see it before because many systems run < 5.4 and so don't have this feature

Comment: Valid syntax in 5.4+. You won't have seen it before if you've been stuck with 5.3.

Comment: @scragar I'd hardly call it "preferred". If you have to use `list()`, you may as well just assign to a variable and use `$var[1]` on the next line. E.g. `list` doesn't help with something like `foo(explode(...)[1])`.

Comment: Thank you all! I think it's a very nice way of getting values from an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called **array dereferencing**, you can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php):

> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. `foo()[0]`.

Another bit of information [here](http://php.net//manual/pl/language.types.array.php):

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

Why does it work? Because you are using PHP/5.4 or greater: [Function array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). In earlier versions, you had to store the result in a variable before being able to access individual bits:

```
$key = 'question_1';
$key = explode('_', $key);
$key = $key[1];
var_dump($key);
```

Though, for this particular case, good old [list()](http://php.net/list) (available since PHP/4) is just as fancy:

```
$key = 'question_1';
list(,$key) = explode('_', $key);
var_dump($key);
```

On this line, PHP/5.5 adds a new variant: [array and string literal dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.const-dereferencing). It's the same, except that for array/string literals (rather than function calls).

Comment: That's not *literal* dereferencing.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'll fix it ASAP.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to leave a wrong answer intentionally :)